# Dock ToolWindowPane at the same location as the Output and Error List windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, docking

How can I dock (tabbed) a ToolWindowPane at the same location as the Visual Studio Output and Error List window?

These are some code snippets of my project:

Create ToolWindowPane

```
  ToolWindowPane window = this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), 0, true);
  IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
```

To retrieve the Output window:

```
   DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
   Window win = dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput);
```

Test code (docks the window above the output window)

```
windowFrame.SetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_FrameMode, VSFRAMEMODE.VSFM_Dock);
```

Answer (score 0):

To dock the ToolWindow you need to set the Window property and use one of the EnvDTE.Constants.

```
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), Style = VsDockStyle.Tabbed, Orientation =ToolWindowOrientation.Bottom, Window = EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput)]
```